# Navigate to next page on button click event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, button

I have a button that runs some code when clicked. It then updates its text. I would like the same button to navigate to next page when clicked.

Right now, it automatically goes to NewPage. How can I make it such that when it's clicked, it goes to next page?

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // some code here
    Button1.Content = "Next";
    // here is the problem
    NewPage np = new NewPage();
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(np);
}
```

Comment: And what is that "next page"? Please include the entire code related to this issue. Best regards,

Comment: what is "next page" ?

Comment: @AlexBell Its a Page in WPF.

Comment: Have you tried `this.NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(NextPage);` ?

Comment: @ganchito55 it works. But I want the navigation to take place after the user click on the button (button1) again. Thanks

Comment: @Imsa so you want that the first time it only changes the button content and in the second time you navigate to NextView?

Comment: @ganchito55 correct! first time button1 is clicked, it changes it's content to "Next", and if clicked again, go to NextPage. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a global bool variable `bool isSecondClick = false;` and when user clicks on the button for the first time set `isSecondClick = false;` and change the text on the button. On the second click go the next page.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{         
        if (isSecondClick)
        {   
            NewPage np = new NewPage();
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(np);            
        }
        else
        { 
            Button1.Content = "Next";
            isSecondClick = true;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your Button with a Tag:
`<Button Tag="1" ...`

Then you can use this tag to know if you need to change the text or navigate:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if(Button1.Tag==1){
       Button1.Content = "Next";
       Button1.Tag=2;
       return;
    }
    if(Button1.Tag==2){
       this.NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(NextPage);
       Button1.Tag=1;
       return;
    }      

}
```

I hope that code helps you.

Comment: Thanks! However, it still doesn't wait for second click to navigate to NextPage. @PLOW's answers is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Imsa sorry I had a mistake, I forgot the return :S